# Python - Read from text file and amalgamate information

Tags: python-3.x, enumerate, readlines, startswith

I have data in a text file that i have no problem reading but need to remove duplicate names and string the values together. See below:

```
boris:1
boris:3
boris:8
tim:4
tim:5
tim:2
ella:3
ella:9
ella:6
```

I need to remove the duplicate names and add the values to a single line, as such:

```
boris:1:3:8
tim:4:5:2
ella:3:9:6
```

Everything i have tried so far either shows all of the values with repeating names or only shows the last entry. Methods that have been tried are below:

```
file = open ("text1.txt", 'r')
for line in file:
values = line.strip().split(":")
name = values[0]
print(values[0], values[1]) #for checking to see values held
    for index, item in enumerate(line):
        for num in range(3):
            val = {}
            if index ==0:
                name = item
            if index == 1:
                scr1 = item
            val[str(num)] = name + str(scr1)
        print(num)
print(name, scr1)
```

I have also tried:

```
for line in file.readlines():
line = line.split(":")
#print(line)
for n, item in enumerate(line):
    #print(n, line1)
    if n == 0:
        name = item
        #print(name)
        if item.startswith(name):
            line[n] = item.rstrip() # i'm sure that here is where i'm going wrong but don't know how to solve
        #else:
            #line[n] = item.rstrip()
print(":".join(line))
#print(line)
```

Whilst these work to some degree I cant get the answers i'm looking for - any help is greatly appreciated.
The result ends up looking something like:

```
boris:1
boris:3
boris:8
tim:4
tim:5
tim:2
ella:3
ella:9
ella:6
```

Which is where i started.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to store the whole data set in memory (actually, it is possible to avoid it which is needed if you have very large data set, but it will be harder to implement).
You need to create a `dict` to store values in it. When you encounter new name you will create new dict item, and when you encounter already existing name, you will append its value to corresponding dict item.

Here is an example code:

```
dataset = dict()
# first, if we use `with` then file will be closed automatically
with open('text1.txt', 'r') as f:
    # when we want to just iterate over file lines, we can omit `readlines` and use this simple syntax
    for line in f:
        # strip() is important, because each line we read ends with '\n' character - and we want to strip it off.
        # partition() returns tuple of left-part, separator and right-part,
        # but we don't need that separator value so we assign it to a dummy variable.
        # rpartition() is better choice if name may contain ':' character in it.
        name, _, value = line.strip().rpartition(':')
        if name not in dataset:  # newly encountered name?
            # here we create a new `list` holding our value
            dataset[name] = [value]
        else:
            # append the value to existing list
            dataset[name].append(value)

# now print out resulting data
for name, values in dataset.items():
    print(':'.join([name] + values))
```

If you need to retain original names order then just replace `dict` with `OrderedDict` from `collections` module.

A little explanation of what happens in the last part:
we iterate over pairs `(name, values)`. Then for each pair we crate a list holding just `name`, concatenate that list with `values` list, then join resulting list using `:` as a separator, and print it out.

Comment: Thank you so much - this one has been driving me nuts - this worked spot on. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need a temporary datastructure that you fill while iterating over the file and then print.

```
names = {}
with open("text1.txt", 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        name, value = line.split(":")
        if name not in names:
            names[name] = []
        names[name].append(value.rstrip())
for name, values in names.items():
    print(name + ":" + ":".join(values))
```

Edit: Too slow :D

Comment: Using `split` is probably not the best option: if we happen to have no `:` in the line then `split` will return list of 1 item, and we will fail with `ValueError` (too many values to unpack). The same will happen if we have too many `:`-s.
On the other side, `partition` will return empty strings for parts it failed to find.

Comment: Huh TIL. I'll leave it here so others can see.

Comment: Brilliant - thanks this also did exactly what i needed.